# Representation variety in $\mathrm{SU}(p,q)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, geometric-representation-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$Let $\Gamma$ be a cocompact oriented Fuchsian group, and consider the representation variety $\textrm{Hom}(\Gamma, \SU(p,q))$. Consider a point $\rho : \Gamma \to \SU(p,q)$ with image $\rho(\Gamma) =\SU(p)\times \SU(q)$, a maximal compact subgroup of $\SU(p,q)$. How to decide whether $\rho$ is nonsingular or not? A result of André Weil gives a sufficient condition to decide whether a point, say $\lambda: \Gamma \to G$  with image $H$  of the representation variety is nonsingular or not, namely the centralizer of $H$ in $G$ has dimension zero. But, this criterion is not applicable here because the centralizer of $\SU(p)\times \SU(q)$ in $\SU(p,q)$ has dimension $1$.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is always a singular point in $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma, \mathrm{SU}(p,q))$.  Suppose $G$ is reductive and $\frak{g}$ its Lie algebra.  Let $\rho \in  \mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma, G)$. Then $\rho$ induces a $\Gamma$-module structure on $\frak{g}$ by the Adjoint action of $G$ on $\frak{g}$.  Then the Zariski tangent space at $\rho$ is the group-cocycle space $T := Z^1(\Gamma, \frak{g})$.  The dimension of $T$ is
$$(2g - 1)\dim(G) + \dim(Z(\rho)),$$
where $g$ is the genus of the surface associated with $\Gamma$ and $Z(\rho)$ is the centralizer of the image of $\rho$.

In your case, $\dim(Z(\rho)) = 1$ while at a smooth point, $\dim(Z(\rho)) = 0$.  So $\rho$ is singular.

Comment: Can you please give. the source of the proof of the formula you gave above... because .. in my case.. $\Gamma$ is a cocompact oriented Fuchsian group, not necessarily just a surface group....

Comment: @user49908,  "The symplectic nature of fundamental groups of surfaces" by Goldman, Adv in Math.

Comment: Is the formula valid even for a cocompact oriented Fuchsian group?

Comment: My understanding is that being cocompact Fuchsian means the upper half plane modulo $\Gamma$ is a Riemann surface of genus $g$.  Also, as far as I can tell, the cocycle computation in Goldman's paper is not particular to $\Gamma$ being a surface group.

Comment: In section 1.1 you may find the paragraph " in the special case at hand...  admits a presentation with 2p generators ..  subject to a single relation" . I guess the author deals only surface groups. A general cocompact oriented Fuchsian group has additional "torsion" generators.